# TypeError: 'function' object does not support item assignment. accessories["first_number"]= all_nr["The result"] how can i make this part work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, calculator

```
from art import logo
print (logo)
from replit import clear
all_nr = {}
def operators (operator, n1,n2):
  if operator == "+":
      result = n1 + n2
      all_nr ['The result'] = result
      return round(result,2)
  elif operator == "-":
      result =n1 - n2
      all_nr ['The result'] = result
      return round(result,2)
  elif operator == "*":
      result = n1 * n2
      all_nr ['The result'] = result
      return round(result, 2)
  elif operator == "/":
      result = n1 / n2
      all_nr ['The result'] = result
      return round(result, 2)
conti_cal = True
def accessories():
  accessories = {}
  accessories["first_number"] = float(input("What is the first number?: "))
  print(""" +
  -
  *
  / 
  """
  )
  accessories["operator"] = input("Pick an operator: ")
  accessories["second_number"] = float(input("What is your second number?: "))
  return(operators(accessories["operator"], accessories["first_number"], 
  accessories["second_number"]))
while conti_cal:
  print(accessories())
  conti = input("type 'yes' to contiue calculate, otherwise type 'no':")
  if conti == "yes":
    conti_cal =True
    **accessories["first_number"]= all_nr["The result"]** 
  else:
    clear()
    conti_cal = True
```

#how can I make the highlighted part work? Can anyone explain to me, in detail? Or what different way how can I make it work. I want to change the value of accessories["first_number"] to the last result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your error is that in the line

> `accessories["first_number"] = all_nr["The result"]`

you are not assigning to the dictionary in the function `accessories` but to the function itself. This, however, is not what you want as you try to add it to the dict `accessories` within this function. Therefore, an easy solution would be to put the dict `accessories_dict`, renamed to avoid confusion, outside of the function as you have done with `all_nr`.

I also changed `conti_cal = True` in the `else` body to `False` to exit the `while` loop.

```py
all_nr = {}
accessories_dict = {}

def operators(operator, n1, n2):
    if operator == "+":
        result = n1 + n2
        all_nr['The result'] = result
        return round(result, 2)
    elif operator == "-":
        result = n1 - n2
        all_nr['The result'] = result
        return round(result, 2)
    elif operator == "*":
        result = n1 * n2
        all_nr['The result'] = result
        return round(result, 2)
    elif operator == "/":
        result = n1 / n2
        all_nr['The result'] = result
        return round(result, 2)


conti_cal = True


def accessories():
    
    accessories_dict["first_number"] = float(
        input("What is the first number?: "))
    print(""" +
  -
  *
  / 
  """
          )
    accessories_dict["operator"] = input("Pick an operator: ")
    accessories_dict["second_number"] = float(
        input("What is your second number?: "))

    return(operators(accessories_dict["operator"], accessories_dict["first_number"],
                     accessories_dict["second_number"]))


while conti_cal:
    print(accessories())
    conti = input("type 'yes' to contiue calculate, otherwise type 'no':")
    if conti == "yes":
        conti_cal = True
        accessories_dict["first_number"] = all_nr["The result"]
    else:
        conti_cal = False
```